# Copy an Image with Drop Shadow and Tranparent Background

Tags: php, image-processing, image-manipulation

I tried to duplicate a PNG image, which has drop shadow (i.e. alpha channel) and transparent background. However, the resulting image paints the shadow and transparent background with black. I tried with `imagecopy` and `imagecopymerge`; neither yielded to valid results, which aren't the same with the original image.

[Preview of the images.](http://savvy.siku-siku.com/lab/php-imagecopy/)

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng('img_box3-bg.png');

/* Using imagecopy. */
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(116, 100);
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 100);
imagepng($dest, 'img_box3-bg.imagecopy.png');
imagedestroy($dest);

/* Using imagecopymerge. */
$dest2 = imagecreatetruecolor(116, 100);
imagecopymerge($dest2, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 100, 100);
imagepng($dest2, 'img_box3-bg.imagecopymerge.png');
imagedestroy($dest2);

imagedestroy($src);
```

Help? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng('img_box3-bg.png');

/* Using imagecopy. */
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(116, 100);

// this is new
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dest, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($dest, 0, 0, $transparent);

imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
```

Comment: I think you meant `$dest` instead of `$img` in the snippet above. This unfortunately didn't do the trick. Take a look at the link / preview page again: I've added a new image that was done using the suggested methods.

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com changed the example, this is working on my test machine. Hope it helps!